# Counter in contiki

Tags: counter, iot, contiki

I'm trying to program Zolertia z1 node in Contiki, i need counter to go from 0 to 120, etimer should be set to 1 second delay(etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND)), and when i try to do counting it's constantly printing out same number (0 or 1), i think i should use PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et)) and probably etimer_restart,and after each second counter should be incremented and printed out (1, 2 ,3 ...), but obviously I'm not doing something correct in while loop or functions are not good?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
  static struct etimer et;
  static int counter;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND);

  while(1) {
    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
    printf("timer called, counter=%u\n", counter++);
    etimer_reset(&et);
  }

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

Potential pitfalls:

- there is no process-local storage for in-process variables in Contiki
  [processes](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Processes). Meaning - if you want to save the values of local
  variables across yields (such as `PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL`), declare
  them as static. Most likely this is the problem you're facing, as it woul lead to the counter value being reset.
- `etimer_restart` will drift, use `etimer_reset` instead to get the duration of exactly 120 seconds.

Comment: I managed to do counter, next thing I have to do is when button on Zolertia clicked, counter reverse it's direction, so instead counter++, it goes counter--, but I'm having troubles with combining PROCESS_EVENTS (I suppose I need 2 kinds of events, one for counter and one for button clicks)?

Comment: @NSX23 Please make another question for that!